# Check specific process is elevated in delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, token, elevation, security-identifier

I have the following code that can help to check whether the process is running under elevated.

[image: img1]

How can I modify the code in order to allow it to check whether a certain process is elevated?

```pascal
function IsElevated: Boolean;
const
  TokenElevation = TTokenInformationClass(20);
type
  TOKEN_ELEVATION = record
    TokenIsElevated: DWORD;
  end;
var
  TokenHandle: THandle;
  ResultLength: Cardinal;
  ATokenElevation: TOKEN_ELEVATION;
  HaveToken: Boolean;
begin
  if CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
  begin
    TokenHandle := 0;
    HaveToken := OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread, TOKEN_QUERY, True, TokenHandle);
    if (not HaveToken) and (GetLastError = ERROR_NO_TOKEN) then
      HaveToken := OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, TokenHandle);
    if HaveToken then
    begin
      try
        ResultLength := 0;
        if GetTokenInformation(TokenHandle, TokenElevation, @ATokenElevation, SizeOf(ATokenElevation), ResultLength) then
          Result := ATokenElevation.TokenIsElevated <> 0
        else
          Result := False;
      finally
        CloseHandle(TokenHandle);
      end;
    end
    else
      Result := False;
  end
  else
    Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: In the first place, how do you find the process of interest?

Comment: process name or pid

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is almost in your question...

The function `IsElevated` get the result from [GetTokenInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation) which takes a `TokenHandle`. That `TokenHandle` is given by [OpenProcessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocesstoken) which receives the current process handle.

Now you are interested not by current process but by another for which you have `ProcessID`. So you get process handle you need by calling [OpenProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) with `processID`. It is likely you need elevated privilege to do that.

Comment: `OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, TokenHandle); `
is it replace the 'GetCurrentProcess' to PID?

Comment: I added links to Windows API functions. ProcessID ==> OpenProcess ==> OpenProcessToken ==> GetTokenInformation ==> TokenElevation.

Comment: If my answer fits your needs, please mark it as accepted (The check mark on the left of the answer). Thanks.